# mongodb 3.2 :Error not authorized on admin to execute command on new installation

Tags: mongodb

I just install mongodb 3.2 on my Windows 8.1 64bit and run the server with below command:

> mongod --dbpath "d:\mongodb\data"'

and run `mongo`, when I try to create a new user for root access with below command, I get error,

```
db.createUser(
... {
... user: "admin",
... pwd: "1",
... roles: [ "root" ]
... }
... )
```

error below:
[image: mongodb 3.2 error in creating root user]

Comment: it seems that I can't do any work on my mongodb, even when try `show dbs` command, I got this error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find my fault , I have Bitnami server in my Windows and when I run `mongo` command, in fact I connected to Bitnami mongodb instance.

I stop the Bitanmi and my problem solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `security.authorization` is disabled in the config.

The [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#add-users-before-enabling-access-control) says:

> Add Users **Before** Enabling Access Control

Comment: Thanks but How can I ensure about disabled `security.authorization` ?

Comment: Open the config file in a text editor and find a string "    authorization:". Set its value to "disabled", save the file, and restart mongod.

Comment: But my mongodb's folder just have a bin folder. and there isn't any config file.

Comment: Oh, somehow I missed it is a Windows installation. If there is no config, it should be ok. Must be system permissions then. Do you have any logs on Windows?

Comment: I create a config file and set disabled for security.authorization in it according to https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ , but the problem didn't solved.

Comment: Yes, it is disabled by default. As I was saying, if there is no config file, that's ok. Check what's in the log.

Comment: 'Error: couldn't add user: No role named root@test '